# Optimizing time and space complexity of algorithm

Tags: optimization, time-complexity, space-complexity

How can this be optimized so that it gets more efficient in both time and space complexity, while resulting in the same output?

```
def not-optimal(A):
   N = len(A)
   result = 0
   for i in xrange(N):
      for j in xrange(N):
        if A[i] == A[j]:
            result = max(result, abs(i - j))
```

Comment: What is your goal? Is this a purely theoretical question? If so, you should ask the question at [the CS stackexchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It is not theoretical, we are supposed to write new code that optimizes the above functionality. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best not to start with the code, but to start with the idea of what this code does. This code returns the maximum distance between any two elements in the array that are equal to one another. The question now is whether you can find a different algorithm that accomplishes this same goal is less time or space.

You can trade time for space here in a few different ways. Here's one simple option: create a hash table mapping each element to the *last* index at which it appears. This takes expected time O(n). Then, iterate across the array a second time and, for each element, look at the index of the last copy of that element and compute the distance to that element, tracking the largest one you've seen so far. This second step takes time O(n), so the overall algorithm takes expected time O(n) and uses space O(n). This is a time improvement on the O(n<sup>2</sup>) time, O(1)-space algorithm you have above.

You can't asymptotically improve on the space complexity of this algorithm, since it uses space O(1). At best you'll be shaving off a constant factor from the space usage, but your algorithm is so space efficient that I can't imagine this really would matter.

Hope this helps!